# Saving Qgis project as KML

Tags: qgis, convert, google-earth

Is there a way to take your QGIS project and save the grouping, styles, and layer names as is and turn them into a KML file to open in google earth?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not Easily, but it is getting better.
There is a plugin called Layer2KMZ that DOES work, but it is still quite limited.

I am trying to help with the development, and I am very encouraged by the devs responses to my needs.

Please try it and offer suggestions. Here is the GitHub, but it can easily be installed from within QGIS as a plug-in: https://github.com/ptarroso/layer2kmz

zeddock